# Batch rename and merge folders by year and month (exported from Photos, Mac)

Tags: macos, rename, photos, finder

I am trying to re-organize ~1000 folders that were created after exporting pictures from the Photos app.

The folders have the structure [Month][space][D/DD][,][space][YYYY]. For some dates, two or more folders may exist which contain a random string before the date which is based on location information. I don't need to retain that information.

The goal is to end up with one folder for each YYYY_MM which contains all photos from that month.
Can this be done with base unix? I imagine the script would do something like

- parse all folders, extract year, month and day info for each given folder
- create new folders called YYYY_MM
- move photos into this folder
- If there is a file name conflict it should be resolved by appending a sequential integer.

Here is an example for folder names:

> 'July 1, 2010', 'Berkhamsted, England - Mill Street, July 1, 2010', 'July 1, 2011', 'July 1, 2012', '...', 'July 2, 2010'

Reorganize folders to this structure:

> '2009_01', '2009_02', '2009_03', '2010_', '2011_', '2012_'

Many thanks

Comment: Where is your code sample. Do you expect us to write the code for you?

Comment: No, because I wouldn't learn anything from that. Could you point me to a resource where I may find suitable commands? I assume the solution would involve something like setting the directory, parsing folder names with a wildcard (to account for the variable string), recognizes the specific date structure after the possible wildcard and stores that information in a variable. Then for each existing Year Month Date in that variable it would create a new folder and then move all files from the folders into the new folder… Thanks!